# Is there a standard way to deploy an application with SQL Server express?

Tags: .net, deployment, connection-string, sql-server-express, app-config

In Winforms or WPF
Is there a standard way to deploy an application with SQL Server express? 
Is there a standard way to create a local SQL Server express database and also update the app.config connectionStrings settings during an application install?

Answer (score 0):

Click Once is the "standard" solution to deploying SQL Express with your application.